# git clone -c core.symlinks=true does not work

Tags: git, git-submodules, symlink

I try to clone a repository with submodules and symlinks.
I'm on Windows 10 and clone onto an NTFS SSD.

I'm cloning with

`$git clone -c core.symlinks=true --recurse-submodules -b develop git@example.com/my-project.git`

When cloned, the config contains the line `symlinks = false` and the symlinks are not created.

I have to use

`$git config core.symlinks true`

`$git reset --hard`

after cloning to create the symlinks.

Why does it not work when cloning directly?

Comment: Try `git -c core.symlinks=true clone --recurse-submodules -b develop git@example.com/my-project.git`. `-c name=value` should be between `git` and the sub-command.

Comment: The issue should not happen again with Git 2.21+ (Q1 2019). See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54058445/6309)

Answer (score 4):

When the `git clone` code creates the new (empty) repository, it uses the `init_db` function, which [ends with a block including this code](https://github.com/git/git/blob/fe0a9eaf31dd0c349ae4308498c33a5c3794b293/builtin/init-db.c#L272-L289):

```
/* Check if symlink is supported in the work tree */
path = git_path_buf(&buf, "tXXXXXX");
if (!close(xmkstemp(path)) &&
    !unlink(path) &&
    !symlink("testing", path) &&
    !lstat(path, &st1) &&
    S_ISLNK(st1.st_mode))
        unlink(path); /* good */
else
        git_config_set("core.symlinks", "false");
```

Since you are getting an explicit `core.symlinks = false`, this line must be overriding your request to set `core.symlinks = true`.  Note that the setting depends on the actual OS support, rather than any command line option.  However, if you *move* the work-tree elsewhere later, the explicit setting remains in the `.git/config` file.

Meanwhile, there are two other issues.   One is what [ElpieKay mentioned in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49893450/git-clone-c-core-symlinks-true-does-not-work#comment86804180_49893450):  For *most* commands, you can temporarily override the configuration using `git -c name=value subcommand`, which would be `git -c core.symlinks=true clone arguments`.  This is worth trying, in case your particular Git version is out of date and does not match the code I am quoting and linking-to here.

However, `git clone` is quite special: it's essentially an optional `mkdir` to create the repository and work-tree directories, followed by a `git init`, followed by some configuration setting, followed by a `git fetch` and a `git checkout`.  So this means you *can* use `git -c name=value clone -c name=value ...`.  The *first* `name=value` setting is in use while the repository gets created, i.e., during `git init`.  The *second* `name=value` is the one that `git clone` drops into the new clone, using [this bit of code](https://github.com/git/git/blob/fe0a9eaf31dd0c349ae4308498c33a5c3794b293/builtin/clone.c#L1047-L1054):

```
init_db(git_dir, real_git_dir, option_template, INIT_DB_QUIET);

if (real_git_dir)
        git_dir = real_git_dir;

write_config(&option_config);

git_config(git_default_config, NULL);
```

The `write_config` function is where Git writes your `core.symlinks=true` from your `git clone -c core.symlinks=true ...` command.  So this in theory *should* override the `core.symlinks=false` setting that `init_db` computed.  This is the part I find curious: that it *doesn't*.

The subsequent `git_config` call reads the actual config written into the new repository's `.git/config`.  This will set the internal `has_symlinks` variable, which will control the internal `git checkout` that `git clone` runs.  So if this did override the `init_db` setting, everything would work just the way you want.  What's not obvious is why it doesn't override.  The code here is a bit twisty, but it seems like your command-line option *should* override the `init_db` setting.

(Of course, if symlinks actually work in the work-tree, the `init_db` code should not be setting `core.symlinks=false` in the first place!)

Answer (score 1):

That should be fixed with Git 2.21 (Q1 2019)

Refspecs configured with "`git -c var=val clone`" did not propagate to the resulting repository, which has been corrected.

See [commit 7eae4a3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7eae4a3ac4084e6f01bbab2847a399ea5677a099), [commit 515be83](https://github.com/git/git/commit/515be8338237c1f0f98ff826ba98f50d1dff5517), [commit 3e42cb3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3e42cb3b67bef525d4bd8416d44ac1f1a1f7a495) (14 Nov 2018) by [SZEDER Gábor (`szeder`)](https://github.com/szeder).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 84d1783](https://github.com/git/git/commit/84d178316fbe7e93b11e34604fcee86812802986), 04 Jan 2019)</sup>

> ### clone: respect additional configured fetch refspecs during initial fetch
>
> The initial `fetch` during a clone doesn't transfer refs matching additional `fetch` refspecs given on the command line as configuration variables, e.g. '`-c remote.origin.fetch=<refspec>`'.
>   This contradicts the documentation stating that configuration variables specified via
>   '`git clone -c <key>=<value> ...`' "take effect immediately after the repository is initialized, but before the remote history is fetched" and the given example specifically mentions "adding additional fetch refspecs to the origin remote".
>
> Furthermore, one-shot configuration variables specified via '`git -c <key>=<value> clone ...`', though not written to the newly created repository's config file, live during the lifetime of the '`clone`' command, including the initial fetch.
>
> All this implies that any fetch refspecs specified this way should already
>   be taken into account during the initial fetch.
>
> The reason for this is that the initial fetch is not a fully fledged '`git fetch`' but a bunch of direct calls into the fetch/transport machinery with clone's own refs-to-refspec matching logic, **which bypasses parts of '`git fetch`' processing configured fetch refspecs**.
>   This logic only considers a single default refspec, potentially influenced by options like '`--single-branch`' and '`--mirror`'.
>
> The configured refspecs are, however, already read and parsed properly
>   when clone calls `remote.c:remote_get()`, but it never looks at the parsed refspecs in the resulting '`struct remote`'.
>
> **Modify `clone` to take the remote's configured fetch refspecs into account to retrieve all matching refs during the initial fetch**.
>
> Note that we have to explicitly add the default fetch refspec to the remote's refspecs, because at that point the remote only includes the fetch refspecs specified on the command line.
>
> Add tests to check that refspecs given both via '`git clone -c ...`' and '`git -c ... clone`' retrieve all refs matching either the default or the additional refspecs, and that it works even when the user specifies an alternative remote name via '`--origin=<name>`'.

Caveat:

> Due to limitations in the current implementation, some configuration variables specified via '`git clone -c var=val`' (or '`git -c var=val clone`') are ignored during the initial `fetch` and `checkout`.
>
> Let the users know which configuration variables are known to be ignored ('`remote.origin.mirror`' and '`remote.origin.tagOpt`') under the documentation of '`git clone -c`', along with hints to use the options '`--mirror`' and '`--no-tags`' instead.

The [man page for `git clone`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7eae4a3ac4084e6f01bbab2847a399ea5677a099/Documentation/git-clone.txt#L183-L197) now includes:

> Due to limitations of the current implementation, some configuration variables do not take effect until after the initial fetch and checkout.
>
> Configuration variables known to not take effect are:
>
> - `remote.<name>.mirror`
> - `remote.<name>.tagOpt`.
>
> Use the corresponding `--mirror` and `--no-tags` options instead.